# PHP calculating two arrays and then add their sum

Tags: php, arrays, sum, multiplication

I want to calculate an array to another array and then add both like this :

```
   Array1(4,8,7,12);
   Array2(3,6);
```

the result is like this :
3x4+3x8+3x7+3x12+6x4+6x8+6x7+6x12 = 279

I tried with this code and since I'm still new with php I still didn't make any tips I'll be glad thanks in advance

```
<?php 



tab1(4,8,7,12);
tab2(3,6);
$s=0;
for($i=0; $i<$tab1[3]; $i++){
       for($j=0; $j<$tab2[1]; $j++){
           $s = $s + tab[i] * tab[j];
}
echo "$s";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is kind of homework to me. StackOverflow usually does not accept this kind of question but I'll try to answer it If it is still accepting answers.

Comment: thank you Khayyam!! I just for tips not the whole solution but I understand if it shouldnt be here I'll delete it asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a piece of cake. I am not sure what `tab1` means but I assume you are trying to use this function to get an array of desired(input) numbers.

Using a `foreach` loop to loop over the two arrays, I came up with the code below:

```php
<?php
$a = [4,8,7,12];
$b = [3,6];
$sum = 0;
foreach ($b as $valueInB) {
    foreach ($a as $valueInA) {
        $sum += $valueInA * $valueInB;
    }
}
echo $sum;
?>
```

which results in:

```
279
```

if you are insisting on using a `for` loop you can run the code below to get the same result:

```php
<?php
$a = [4,8,7,12];
$b = [3,6];
$sum = 0;
$bLength = count($b);
$aLength = count($a);
for ($i=0; $i < $bLength  ; $i++) { 
    $valueInB = $b[$i];
    for ($j=0; $j < $aLength ; $j++) { 
        $valueInA = $a[$j];
        $sum += $valueInA * $valueInB;
    }
} 
echo $sum;
?>
```

Please note that you should use the `count` outside of the loop because looping over the array and calling `count` each time is not an efficient way. (Thanks to [Will B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144627/will-b) for the comment)

Comment: for best-performance you should move the `count()` to a variable outside of the `for()` loop call.

Comment: @Rachidaa dear Richard, I highly suggest you avoid chatting in the comments because of the strict rules here at StackOverflow. There are numerous sources to study your favorite programming language, but, personally speaking, nothing has the same value as self-studying and immediately implementing your achieved knowledge. So, I would recommend you to use websites like Codewars which has lots of question and make you think about what you need, and then Google which helps you to understand how to implement what you need

Comment: @WillB. Yea I guess you are right. using count in the loop is not an efficient way. I'll edit this right now. Thanks Will!

Answer (score 1):

For a more simplistic approach without iteration you can use `array_sum` on the two arrays.

Example: https://3v4l.org/3gtgE

```
$a = [4,8,7,12];
$b = [3,6];

$c = array_sum($a) * array_sum($b);
var_dump($c);
```

Result

```
int(279)
```

This works because of the order of operations of:

```
(3*4) + (3*8) + (3*7) + (3*12) + (6*4) + (6*8) + (6*7) + (6*12) = 279
```

Equates to the same as the sum of `a` multiplied by the sum of `b`:

```
(4+8+7+12) * (3+6) = 279
```

Comment: So sad when the simplest, most direct, most elegant answer isn't accepted.